# Select and count complex sub entities in iOS core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am doing an app which has a similar database relationships like the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSOBG.png

I am struggling about how to count like how many Employees in each Depart, and select top 5 of them. Can anyone help me out of that?
 Many thanks

Comment: What code do you have so far? What does it do wrong?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I just simply have no idea to make that query.

Comment: How many objects are there? Can you fetch all the departments and then sort based on the employee count?

Comment: no, that's what I d like to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a fetch request as normal, with whatever predicate you might want. You can't do the sort using the relationship count in the data store so you need to do one of 2 things:

1: Execute the fetch and then sort using:

```
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"employees.@count" ascending:NO];
```

2: Add a new, non-transient, attribute to the Department which holds the count of the employees (you need to maintain that). Now you can add a sort descriptor to the fetch request and set the fetch limit to 5.